# Footer positioning based on the contents inside template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can I adjust the footer position, after routing if template contents is less it should be fixed in position, contents in another template is more then footer position should be relative. 
In company page footer position should be fixed.
In Category Page footer position should be relative. (Assuming category page has more contents inside div tag )

### app.component.html

```html
<header>
  Header Contents
</header>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
  <li role="presentation" routerLink="/category" routerLinkActive="activeTab">
  <a><span>Category</span></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" routerLink="/company" routerLinkActive="activeTab">
   <a><span>Company</span></a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
  Footer Contents
</footer>
```

### company.html

```html
<section> 
  <md-card>
    <div>

    </div>
 </md-card>
</section>
```

### category.html

```html
<section> 
  <md-card>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <th>XYZ</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Nothing</th>
        </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   </md-card>
 </section>
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: You can get the dynamic height,width of an element even on change. <div #myElem></div> then lets say you want a fixed footer if height or width of myElem is correct.  <footer [class.fixed]="checkWidth(myElem.getBoundingClientRect().width)"></footer>

Comment: for mobile landscape mode also it should apply. So by knowing the content length or if content is not present it should get like length=0 using typescript or javacript

Comment: apply this event as well on your element. (window:resize)="someMethod(myElem.getBoundingClientRect().wid‌​th)" have some boolean that changes depending on the data and give that boolean to the class.fixed. that's should do it.

Comment: thank you i'l try that window resize method

Comment: k let me know i'll post it as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Actually i even tried window resize method but it was not working. Is there any code which can applied to app.compontent.ts file which can be applied from every situation in of different templates

Comment: you could use HostListener inside your ts files and also ViewChild to get the dynamic content width or height on window size change but you might be doing something wrong because window:resize should do the job for you. try posting updated code.

Comment: ok i'l try to add HostListener

Comment: listen if this doesn't work for you, create mini service that footer will listen to and the components will emit data to.

Comment: mini service ???

Comment: You know how to create a service in angular?

Comment: angular 2.. just working with importing plugins of npm which is installed..... or else by using script how can i get length of particular div element like if length==0

Comment: you should go over this https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 once you understand the concept just pass the dynamic components width or height into the service and make sure your footer listens to those changes.

Comment: I have seen that i'l try it again thank u for your suggestions. i'l try on dynamic components of width and heigth